# Error in plotting the dplyr based subsetting of the dataset based on another dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I would like to produce a stacked bar plot based on the subsetting between the two datasets.

`df1` contains the distances between two any items.

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(col.x=rep(LETTERS[1:6], each=10), 
                  col.y=rep(LETTERS[1:6], times=10), 
                  dist=runif(60,0,3))
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(!col.x==col.y)
summary(df1)
# col.x col.y      dist        
# A:8   A:8   Min.   :0.07384  
# B:8   B:8   1st Qu.:0.78300  
# C:8   C:8   Median :1.41564  
# D:8   D:8   Mean   :1.54097  
# E:8   E:8   3rd Qu.:2.29776  
# F:8   F:8   Max.   :2.98281
```

`df2` contains the data associated with all these items where each item has sub-items with different values.

```
set.seed(123)
df2 <- data.frame(col=sample(LETTERS[1:10],50,replace = T), 
                  ET =sample(c('A1','A2','B3','B6','C5'),50,replace = T),
                  EV =sample(1:8,50,replace = T))
summary(df2)
#      col      ET           EV      
# C      : 7   A1:11   Min.   :1.00  
# E      : 7   A2:10   1st Qu.:2.25  
# J      : 6   B3: 9   Median :4.50  
# B      : 5   B6:13   Mean   :4.58  
# F      : 5   C5: 7   3rd Qu.:6.00  
# G      : 5           Max.   :8.00  
# (Other):15
```

In the first step, all the items within a certain distance (`2.5`) to the selected item (`B`) are identified.

```
colY <- df1 %>% filter(col.x=='B' & dist <= 2.5) %>% select(col.y)
```

In the second step, all the associated data for these selected items will be retrieved.

```
datPlot <- df2 %>% filter(col %in% colY$col.y)
```

*Question 1:* Is there any possible way to combine these into a single dplyr statement?

I have tried to plot the stacked barplot to visualize the sub-items with the frequencies of associated values:

```
datPlot %>% group_by(ET) %>% ggplot(aes(ET)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = EV))
```

The below bar plot looks correct but fails to produce a stacked barplot.

[image]

*Question 2:* What is the issue with the above approach?

As my original datasets are huge with atleast 100M rows, I would like to use the fastest approach for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fill` variable is continuous. Make it into a factor. You can also use a `semi_join` to filter the rows of one dataframe by another.

```
datPlot <- df2 %>% semi_join(df1 %>% filter(col.x=='B' & dist <= 2.5), 
                             by = c("col" = "col.y"))

datPlot %>% ggplot(aes(x = ET, fill = as.factor(EV))) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: Thanks, `as.factor()` works ! Is there a possibility of arranging the stacked bars in a sorted way?

Comment: Sorted how? They are currently sorted by value

Comment: Like in `A2` the values are 1, 2, 8 with frequencies 1, 3, 2. Is there anyway these can be sorted within the `A2` bar.